# Magento: Fatal error: Class not found (Google Shopping)

Tags: php, magento

Trying to get [Google Shopping extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-content-api-for-shopping.html) running on Magento Enterprise Magento ver. 1.10.1.1

**Catalog > Google Content > Manage Attributes** throws *this error:*

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Resource/Type/Collection.php on line 35
```

**Catalog > Google Content > Manage Attributes > Add Attribute Mapping** throws *this error:*

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleShopping/Model/Resource/Type.php on line 35
```

I installed the extension by copying the files via FTP, not using the Magento Connect manager if that makes any difference?

I'm not sure where to go from here? Google isn't being very productive on this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a xml file to 'app/etc/modules' dir? I recommend to install the extension using Magento Connect.